How do I make a object(e.g. head) get controlled by multiple bones?
I wanted to make an enemy character whose head gets caved in as player hits a headshot upon it, so I tried to make the head controlled by three bones(from rigging with amature), where only one middle bones shrink while the others stay same to provide the effect. But when I tried pose mode, I couldn't quite make the desired movement. The best I could do was to only make two bones act same, both only shrinking the head as whole.


You could add another new middle bone (4 in total), and make the new bone, and the left and right bones children of the old middle bone (Ctrl+P, Make Parent >Keep Offset). The old middle bone will rotate and tilt the head, while the child bones can do the deformation when you scale them individually. Another option is Shape Keys (depends on the game engine, I guess)
